# React/Typescript Can't render a React.Fragment inside <tbody>:

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to use a map to render `<tr>` elements within a `<tbody>`.  This conditionally will render a second `<tr>` if there is additional content to be displayed under first `<tr>`.  I have wrapped both in a `React.Fragment` and this is working fine, but when running the tests I get:
**Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): %s cannot appear as a child of <%s>.%s%s%s**

**Table:**

```
<table className='document-table borderless row-height-sm'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          {tableData.headers.map((th) => (
            <th key={`document-table-th-${th.value}`}>{intl.formatMessage(th.descriptor, { value: th.value })}
              <button onClick={() => { sortRows(th.value) }} className='ghost'>
                <Icon data-ref="action-item-chevron" role="img" name='sort' aria-label="Sort arrows" />
              </button>
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       {sortedTableRows.map((tr, i) => (
        <DocumentTableRow 
          key={tr.id}
          rowData={tr}
          rowIndex={i}
          openRows={openRows}
          setOpenRows={setOpenRows}
        />
       ))}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Table Row:**

```
return (
            <React.Fragment>
             <tr key={`document-table-tr-${rowData.id}`}>
               {rowData.values.map((td, j) => (
                 <td className={`document-table-td-${j} ${j === rowData.values.length - 1 ? 'flex align-items-center justify-content-space' : ''}`} key={`document-table-td-${td.sortKey.replace(' ', '-')}`}>
                   {intl.formatMessage(td.descriptor, {value: td.value})}
                   {j === rowData.values.length - 1 && 
                   <button onClick={() => { rowData.additionalContent && rowData.additionalContent.value ? setOpenRow(rowIndex) : null }} className='ghost'>
                      <Icon data-ref={`document-table-row-${rowIndex}`} role="img" name={`chevron-${openRows[rowIndex] ? 'up' : 'down'}`} aria-label="Expand row" />
                   </button>
                   }
                 </td>
               ))}
              </tr>
             {rowData.additionalContent && rowData.additionalContent.value && openRows[rowIndex] &&
                <tr className='additional-content'><td className='pad-left-xl'>{rowData.additionalContent.value}</td></tr>
              }
            </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

**Rendered html:**

```
<table class="document-table borderless row-height-sm">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Document type</th>
        <th>Jurisdiction</th>
        <th>Upload date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="document-table-td-0 ">Passport</td>
        <td class="document-table-td-1 ">Germany</td>
        <td class="document-table-td-2 ">Uploaded 2021-10-12</td>
        <td class="document-table-td-3 flex align-items-center justify-content-space">Rejected</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='additional content'>
      <td>Rejected due to expiration</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Why is it complaining about DOM nesting when the rendered html is valid, and why only in tests and not when rendering the component in the application?